# Access variables from custom process step command

Tags: qt, qt-creator

In Qt Creator, I would like to configure a custom process step to build the project, which needs to access project variables, or at least the path to the `.pro` file.

When I run the built-in `qmake`, the `.pro` file is passed as first parameter, but when using custom step, it does not pass it.

E.g: Built-in

```
C:\...\bin\qmake.exe
C:\...\mywidget.pro
-r
-spec
win32-msvc2013
CONFIG+=debug
```

E.g: Custom

```
C:\...\bin\qmake.exe
-r
-spec
win32-msvc2013
CONFIG+=debug
```

When I set up the command, how to access these information?

I already tried with several options without success:

```
command: C:\...qmake.exe
Arguments: $$TARGET $TARGET $(TARGET) ${TARGET} %{TARGET}% %%{TARGET}%%
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `%{sourceDir}\mywidget.pro` as an argument. Looks like [only `%{buildDir}` and `%{sourceDir}` are available](http://qt-project.org/doc/qtcreator-3.0/creator-build-settings.html#using-qt-creator-variables) which are project specific.

Of course, you cannot use values that are defined in the `.pro` file such as `TARGET` because those are only evaluated while `qmake` is running.

Comment: I have different .pro files included as SUBDIRS, with the default qMake, I can build one of them by right-click on the project and "Build MyClass", that is not possible with custom build step because the .pro files path is not provided?

Comment: You might add some information about what you are trying to do. You can replace the `qmake` and `make` command without adding a custum build step. These changes commands are used to "run qmake" and "rebuild" in sub-projects. E.g. if I add an `-j2` argument to the make command, make will always use two cores.